# Как изменить отсчет системы координат PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

По-умолчанию отсчет в системе координат ведется с верхнего левого угла. 
Как переместить ее в центр сделав похожей на Декартовую систему координат ?

Перемещаю в центр с помощью `TranslateTransform`:

```
graph.TranslateTransform(pictureBox.Width / 2, pictureBox.Height / 2);
```

Но как теперь изменить отсчет `Y` снизу вверх, а не наоборот ?

Answer (score 2):

Вот так:

```
graph.ScaleTransform(1, -1);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhc2xxtx(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Работает, но не очень удобно так как текст стал перевернут. Может есть способ просто установить отсчет Y снизу к верху ? Или единственный вариант вручную менять знак у Y на противоположный у каждой фигуры ?